# Возможно ли получить код ответа сервера при помощи aiohttp?

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiohttp

Собственно, вопрос в шапке. Возможно ли получить код ответа сервера с помощью aiohttp, если да, то как, и намного ли больше это использует ресурсов, чем то же при помощи Requests? Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Пример получения ответа: https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp#client

Comment: Храни тебя господь. Всегда ты выручаешь :D

Comment: @gil9red А, блин. Это я видел и делал. Он возвращает html код. Я неправильно написал вопрос, уже вижу. Мне код ответа сервера нужен.

Comment: Для requests: `rs = requests.head('https://ya.ru/')` `print(rs.status_code)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`session.get(url)` возвращает объект класса [Response](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#response-object), из которого вы можете [получить код ответа](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#response-content-and-status-code):

```
resp = await client_session.get(url)
async with resp:
    print(resp.status)
```